# Installing/using Selenium for Nightwatch.js in C9.io

Tags: selenium, cloud9-ide, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to use [Nightwatch.js](http://nightwatchjs.org/) to do automated unit and end-to-end testing.  Nightwatch.js depends on Selenium.

- I have determined how to install it ( see "Steps to install Selenium" below ), and can get the Selenium server started (via `bin/
  java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar`).
- However, when I try to actually run a basic nightwatch test, I get errors due to browser, url, and port configuration problems (errors below).
- ***Any chance someone can provide some hints on how I should [configure the nightwatch.json](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#settings-file) file to work with Selenium installed into C9?***

---

## Steps to install Selenium

```
mkdir bin
cd bin
wget "http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.48/selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar"
unzip selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar
cd ..
```

## LOG

```
03:26:27.875 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{platform=ANY, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, name=Basic}]])
03:26:27.893 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{platform=ANY, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, name=Basic}]
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:

(process:3585): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Error: no display specified

        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:122)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:117)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:129)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.callConstructor(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:91)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.newInstance(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:68)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:222)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
03:27:13.875 WARN - Exception thrown
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
System info: host: 'metasean-learnin-nightwatch-2330511', ip: '172.17.33.167', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.2.0-c9', java.version: '1.7.0_85'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:183)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.<init>(DefaultSession.java:119)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(DefaultSession.java:95)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(DefaultDriverSessions.java:124)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:58)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:1)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:111)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleRequest(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:175)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:202)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:164)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:130)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:428)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.dispatch(ServletHandler.java:680)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:571)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1526)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1479)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:920)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
        at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:358)
        at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:537)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
System info: host: 'metasean-learnin-nightwatch-2330511', ip: '172.17.33.167', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.2.0-c9', java.version: '1.7.0_85'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.callConstructor(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:101)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.newInstance(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:68)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:222)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.callConstructor(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:91)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: 

(process:3585): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Error: no display specified

Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
System info: host: 'metasean-learnin-nightwatch-2330511', ip: '172.17.33.167', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.2.0-c9', java.version: '1.7.0_85'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:134)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:117)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:129)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:

(process:3585): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Error: no display specified

        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:122)
        ... 19 more
03:27:13.884 WARN - Exception: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:

(process:3585): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Error: no display specified
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others in this situation, there's some good news and some bad news.

**The good news ...**

1. At the top of the C9 workspace, click "Preview", then "Preview Running Application".  This will open a new C9 tab.
2. Copy the portion of the new C9 tab's address bar *AFTER* "https://" (e.g. `<project-name>-<username>.c9users.io`).
3. In a C9 terminal, run `ping <project-name>-<username>.c9users.io` (replacing the `<project-name>-<username>.c9users.io` with your info).  This returns an actual ip address.
4. In the `nightwatch.json` file, set the value of the "launch_url" to the returned ip address
5. You can now run `nightwatch`. :-)

**The bad news ...**
 - The first two tests we tried to run involved testing against `browser.url` then `browser.end` and in both cases, nightwatch's `browser` object appears to have been modified somewhere.  We're not sure where or why or how to fix it, but without it, being able to run `nightwatch` isn't going to do us a lot of good.  :-(

Comment: So your problem was nightwatch or selenium?

Comment: @YerkoPalma - My original problem was running Selenium in C9 so that I could use Nightwatch in C9.  I was able to get Selenium running in C9 (that was the good news), but unfortunately, I was unable to get Nightwatch to run in C9 (that was the bad news).